# Problem involving polynomial function and prime numbers

Tags: functions, polynomials, prime-numbers

Let $f$ be a polynomial function, with integer coefficients, strictly increasing on $\Bbb N$ such that $f(0)=1$. Show that it doesn't exist any arithmetic progression of natural numbers with ratio $r>0$ such that the value of function $f$ in every term of the progression is a prime number.
I noticed that the last term of f is 1, due to the fact that $f(0)=1$. I don't know how to continue.

Comment: what do you mean by a ratio of an arithmetic progression ... I tend to reserve the word "ratio" for geometric progressions?

Comment: @Mirko I mean the constant difference between two consecutive terms.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficents. 
Then for any $a,b\in\Bbb Z$, $g(x)=f(ax+b)$ is also a polynomial with integer coefficients.
Assume $g(n)$ is prime for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and let $p=g(1)$. 
Note that $g(n)\bmod p$ is periodic with period $p$. We conclude that $p\mid g(np+1)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. It follows that $g(np+1)-p$ has infinitely many roots and hence (provided $a\ne 0$) also $f(x)-p$ has inifinitely many roots, hence must be the zero polynomial, i.e., $f(x)$ is constant - but it was given that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing!

---

*Remark:* The fact  $f(0)=1$ was not used. And instead of strictly increasing, non-constant suffices.

Comment: Why $g(n)\bmod p$ is periodic with period $p$?